# Iterate over dlang struct

Tags: iteration, d

I have a struct that looks something like this:

```d
struct MultipartMessage {
    ubyte[] mime, data;
    Header header;

    void setSender(string sender) {
        header.sender = sender;
    }
    void setId(int id) {
        header.id = id;
    }
}
```

and I would like to iterate over it, in another class with something like this:

```d
struct Socket {
    ...

    void send(MultipartMessage msg) {
        foreach (part; msg) {
            sendPart(part);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Is this possible?  I'd like to use something analogous to Python's  `__iter__` in the `MultipartMessage` that can return the fields in a specific order, and ideally even run some additional code, like `header.serialize()`.

Ideally I would add a function to `MultipartMessage` that would look something like this (pseudocode):

```d
ubyte[] __iter__() {
    yield mime;
    yield data;
    yield header.serialize(); //header.serialize returns a ubyte[]
}
```

Comment: As stated in the documentation (http://dlang.org/spec/statement.html#ForeachStatement) there are many ways to deal with foreach statements. The easiest is maybe the input range, but without a clear view of what you want each iteration to return it is hard to tell which way is the best for your case. Could you be more precise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to what you want is probably `opApply`.

See http://dlang.org/spec/statement.html , Section `Foreach over Structs and Classes wit opApply`

This will work:

```d
int opApply(int delegate(ref ubyte[]) dg) {
    int result = 0;
    result = dg(mime);
    result = dg(data);
    ubyte[] header_bytes = header.serialize();
    result = dg(header_bytes);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `tupleof`:

```d
foreach (ref part; msg.tupleof)
    sendPart(part);
```

This will call `sendPart` with `mime`, `data` and `header` (the struct's fields, in the order they were declared). You can filter fields by checking their type with e.g. `static if (!is(typeof(part) == Header))`.

To get the field's name, you can use `__traits(identifier)`:

```d
foreach (i, ref part; msg.tupleof)
    writeln(__traits(identifier, msg.tupleof[i]));
```

(`__traits(identifier, part)` would return `part`.)

There's also `__traits(allMembers)`, which also returns methods.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but D's `__iter__` is `opApply`.

Comment: what do you mean by D's `__iter__` is `opApply`?  How could that be used to iterate over a struct?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do iterate over objects in D.

---

One is to implement the *InputRange* API. Input ranges are similar to iterators, but have a different API. Implementing a range interface means that you can use all of the `std.range`/`std.algorithm` functions on your object, such as `map`, `array`, `joiner` and so on.

D doesn't have an `__iter__` function to get an iterator from arbitrary collections, so you will need to implement a function that returns an input range.

```d
import std.range;

auto bytes() {
    return chain(mime, data, header.serialize);
}
```

This will return a `ubyte` input range, consisting of the bytes in `mime`, followed by the bytes in `data`, then in `header.serialize`.

---

You can also implement the `opApply` method on your struct. `opApply` will only work with `foreach`, so you can't use range methods with it, but it allows you to do things like execute the loop body in separate threads.

The gist of `opApply` is that D passes the loop body to `opApply` as a function; that is, `foreach(x; myObj) { body }` is transformed into `myObj.opApply((x) { body })`.

```d
void opApply(void delegate(ubyte[] part) loopbody) {
    loopbody(mime);
    loopbody(data);
    loopbody(header.serialize());
}
```

---

However, instead of either of those options, I recommend that you implement a function on your object that takes an *output range* and writes the data to it.

An output range is an object that accepts other objects, and does something to them. In this case, the output range should accept `ubyte`s, making it similar to an output stream.

```d
void serialize(Range)(ref Range outRange) if(isOutputRange!(Range, ubyte)) {
    put(outRange, mime); -- `put` simply feeds data into the output range
    put(outRange, data);
    header.serialize(outRange); // No longer have to allocate/return a ubyte array
}
```

Example usage, that stores the output into an `Appender`, which can be converted into an array:

```d
import std.array;

auto serializedDataAppender = appender!ubyte();
myMsg.serialize(serializedDataAppender);
auto serializedData = serializedDataAppender.data;
```

If you implement an output range on top of your socket, then that means that the output range solution *does not have to allocate any memory from the heap*.

---

Check out the [Programming in D](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/index.html) book (specifically, the *Ranges* and *More Ranges* sections) for info on how to implement your own ranges.